# Seeking Traffic Analysis Zones (for city of Shenzhen) in computer readable format?

Tags: geospatial, traffic

I'm looking for (something like) shapefiles of Traffic Analisys Zones in the city of Shenzhen. If there are several I would like to get most recent, but any would serve the purpose.

Comment: [This scientific paper](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/GIS-data-of-the-city-of-Shenzhen_fig3_316912924) has a map of Shenzhen Traffic Analysis Zones + Roads. Unfortunately the roads overpower the traffic zones so it probably wouldn't polygonize well, but you could manually digitize the traffic zones reasonably easily. Or you could contact the paper's author and ask where they found the data.

Comment: Thank you! I have seen this very paper looking for answer but it hasn't occured to me that I could contact the authors. I will try to do that first, than perhaps seek help regarding the other suggestion If necessary :)

Comment: I found a nicer [graphic without infrastructure](https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/SNaLeVp9Qqe8FQQCWs6s)